# Making next button in iPAD keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I'm using 3rd party framework in my app. This framework automatically generates multiple textfields in collectionView. I do not need to make any changes in storyboard, but simply instantiate this CustomViewController.
This CustomViewController is subclass of UICollectionViewController.

If I have UITextFields on my viewcontroller in storyboard, I would set UITextFieldDelegate on the textFields.

But I'm not sure what I can do for my situation. In what way, can I achieve to make next button on keyboard? Is there a way to make changes in AppDelegate to show "next" button on every single textfield?

Comment: search returnKeyType in workspace it will show in 3rd party library. and set  self.passwordFormField.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyNext;

Comment: @AvijitNagare I set the type as UIReturnKeyNext and it does show Next on the keyboard. However, when I press it, it doesn't actually move to next textfield but close the keyboard. Can you guess which part is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer IQKeyboardManager for this type of situation. This keyboard manager will automatically detect all type of text input views and put a arrow button in keyboard Inputviews which is very helpful when you have multiple text input in your application on single controller.

Here is the link :https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

It's simple and easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

The  UITextField has `returnKeyType` property, you can set this property is  `UIReturnKeyNext`  to set the keyboard has "next" .

Or, you also use the 3rd party lib [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) .

Hope to help